# Flutter Asset image

Tags: flutter, assets, flutter-assetimage

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "dice-six-faces-one.png".

Exception: Asset not found
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:369:7)

Run Asset image in output

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use local images on your Flutter project you need this:

- Create a folder `assets` in your project directory. 
   The path for the assets folder should be `<my_project_name>/assets`
- Add the images to the created folder.
- Add the image reference to the configuration file `pubspec.yalm`

  ```
  assets:
   - assets/myImage.png
  ```
- How to call the image on your dart code:

  ```
  Image(
     image: AssetImage('assets/myImage.png'),
     fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
  ```

Comment: this is the only simple correct way in the whole internet.